# Php login store passwords in txt

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Now, I know that storing passwords in a text file is not secure, but don't worry. Security is not my goal here, this is like one of those hackme websites.
So, I need to know, how would I store usernames and passwords in a text file, so far I have this array

```
$logins = array('Example' => '123','test' => '123','simon' => '123');
```

and this if statement

```
if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
    /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
    $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
    header("location:index.php");
    exit;
}
```

How would I make it so rather than storing them as a list, I can store them in a text file, and then run the if statement, on the text file?

Comment: WHY??? makes no sense to me

Comment: Have a look at json...

Comment: @Jonasw I think he wants to write a website where users try to "hack" their way in, increasing the difficutly on each hack. What I wonder though, is how he's going to do it if he doesn't even know the basics (like this) himself..

Comment: A database is far easier than manually handling and parsing a file in every request. If you really do not have any database server accessible, then use a simple sqlite database. That is still easier and more efficient than using a hand tailored flat file storage format.

Comment: @arkascha Although I agree with you, you should read the question more carefull. OP wants to create some sort of "hack challange" website. Getting a plain text username / password out of a txt file would be a lot easier for a challange than hacking a database.

Comment: @icecub I _think_ I did read the question carefully... What you suggest is not what I read in the question. The term "hackme website" does not mean that the goal is to have clients hack such a credentials file. And if, then what would be the point? It would be a completely unrealistic challenge. The OP never hints that this credentials file should be hacked, it is clearly said that the reason that a file storage is planned is because security is not the goal, so not important.

Comment: @arkascha I guess we have a different interpretation of the question. I've played around on several of those "hackme websites". An easy challange like "hacking a text file" isn't uncommon there before moving on to the more difficult and realistic challanges. Anyway, OP seems happy with the answer, so no reason to debate over it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a JSON kind of thing and refer it as an array. So, prepare the file first. The contents of `passwords.json` (or `passwords.txt`, call it whatever you want):

```
{}
```

And now, what you need to do is the following:

- Read the contents of the file.
- Parse them into an associative array.
- Check the keys for existence of username.
- Verify the password.

So, ultimately, the code would be something like:

```
<?php
    // Read the file.
    $users = file_get_contents("passwords.json");
    // Convert into an associative array.
    $users = json_decode($users);
    // Get the input from the user.
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    // Check the validity.
    if (array_key_exists($username, $users) && $users[$username] == $password) {
        // Valid user.
        $_SESSION["user"] = array($username, $password);
    } else {
        echo "Not Right!";
    }
?>
```

And if you wanna store the users, then you just need to do the opposite.

1. Get the username and password.
2. Read the original list of users into an array.
3. Append the new username and password.
4. Convert it into JSON.
5. Save it inside the file.

The final code:

```
<?php
    // Read the file.
    $users = file_get_contents("passwords.json");
    // Convert into an associative array.
    $users = json_decode($users);
    // Get the input from the user.
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    // Store the new one into the array.
    $users[$username] = $password;
    // Convert back to JSON.
    $users = json_encode($users);
    // Put it into the file.
    file_put_contents("passwords.json", $users);
?>
```